# How do I gracefully handle Ctrl + C and shutdown Discord Py bot?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm using the Discord.py library to make a python discord bot, and on shutdown or when it gets SIGINIT I want it to run a shutdown handler (update database, close database connections, etc) I have the main python script and also discord cogs that I want to cleanly shutdown. A simple google just says to use a Try/Finally, and just to have it run `client.close()` but it needs to be awaited. So it looks something like this:

```
try:
    bot.run(config["token"])
finally:
    shutdownHandeler()
    bot.close()
```

but it wants me to `await` the bot.close coroutine except I cant do that if its not inside an async function. I'm pretty new to asyncio and discord py so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome! Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with `run()` is that you can't just use `try` - `finally` to implement cleanup, because during the handling for `run()`, discord.py already closed the event loop along with the bot itself. However, during the first phase of `run()`'s cleanup, the `bot.close()` method gets called. So it would be best to run your cleanup operations in that close method:

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    async def async_cleanup(self):  # example cleanup function
        print("Cleaning up!")

    async def close(self):
        # do your cleanup here
        await self.async_cleanup()
        
        await super().close()  # don't forget this!


bot = Bot(None)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Colol! But if I use CTR + C to quit the program how would I call the `async_cleanup` function?

Comment: Dpy automatically calls close() for you when you ctrl c, so whatever code you put at the start of close() would be ran, just don't forget the super call at the end.

Comment: Awesome! And do I need to do anything different for cogs or will each cog also call their own `close()` functions on shutdown?

Comment: Cogs don't have a close method, only the bot has one. If you want to have each cog it's own shutdown handler, you'll need to implement it in the main close method of your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not declare `bot.close()` and `shutdownHandeler()` in an async function then call it when it's necessary, in your `finaly` or in a stop command or anything else you would think of ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30152860)

Comment: @camille: This certainly looks like an answer to me.